# Vertically Centering ul/li Text Relative to an Image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I've looked at several other similar questions trying to incorporate the solution with little success. I have a bootstrap row with two `col-md-6`'s. In the first column is the image, and in the second column is a list . What i would like to do is vertically center the list relative to the image.

Here is what my HTML  looks like:

```
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="500-by-700-image.jpg" >
    </div> <!-- col-md-6 -->

    <div class="col-md-6" >
        <h4 style="font-size: 20px; line-height: 2; ">
            My heeader:
            <br>

            <ul style="text-align: left; ">
                <li>item 1</li>
                <li>item 2</li>
                <li>item 3</li>
            </ul>

        </h4>
    </div> <!-- col-md-6 -->
</div> <!-- row -->
```

Any idea on how I can accomplish this, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looking around I managed to find this bit of code that works:

```
<!-- CSS -->
.vcenter {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}

<!-- HTML -->

<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-6 vcenter"> <!-- NEW -->
        <img class="img-responsive" src="500-by-700-image.jpg" >
    </div> <!-- col-md-6 -->

    <div class="col-md-6 vcenter" > <!-- NEW -->
        <h4 style="font-size: 20px; line-height: 2; ">
            My heeader:
            <br>

            <ul style="text-align: left; ">
                <li>item 1</li>
                <li>item 2</li>
                <li>item 3</li>
            </ul>

        </h4>
    </div> <!-- col-md-6 -->
</div> <!-- row -->
```

Comment: In Bootstrap 4, you could have done this without any css hacks, but I'm guessing you're using Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Correct, I am using Bootstrap 3. I am very tempted to look at Bootstrap 4, but am not yet sure on how much damage I'll be doing by switching, though my product is very much "early days," so I guess this is prob. the best time.

Comment: Well, B4 is almost a complete rewrite of Bootstrap 3. So, almost everything is different...

Answer (score -1):

try this. it works for me....

you must add this css to your code:

```
.col-md-6 ul{
height:inherit;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
width: 100%;
}
```